# Installing sha1sum on git-bash (MinGW)

Tags: git, mingw, sha1

I've been using `git-bash` on Windows 7 a lot. I gather it is a wrapper of MinGW. It has [md5sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) but not [sha1sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum). I'd like to install `sha1sum`, but I can't figure out how.

When I try `mingw-get`, it says "command not found"

When I tried to download `mingw-get` from [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge), I only found an installer for the entire MinGW program but not for `mingw-get`.

How do I install either getting `sha1sum` or getting `mingw-get`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mingw-get` is available at

[sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get)

After you have that installed run

`mingw-get install msys-coreutils`

Comment: thanks for your response.  I downloaded it and ran the installer.  Unfortunately, this is the result:                                                                 Welcome to Git (version 1.7.4-preview20110204)

    McGuiT1@ISTM-L-6328MJ1 ~
$ mingw-get install mysys-coreutils
    sh.exe": mingw-get: command not found

Comment: You need to add mingw-get to your path http://wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29

Comment: update:  I successfully installed mingw-get and then msys-coreutils, but sha1sum command still not found

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for myself by adding a shell function that uses the included openssl to replace the part of sha1sum that I used most often.

```
function openssl_sha1sum() {
    local i nf=0 binary= text=true
    local -a files

    # parse for -b/-t mode output arguments
    for (( i=1; i <= $#; i++ )); do
        case "${!i}" in
            (-t|--text)
                text=true
                binary=
                ;;
            (-b|--binary)
                binary=true
                text=
                ;;
            (-|-[cw]|--help|--version|--status|--check|--warn)
                ;;
            (*)
                let 'nf++'
                files[$nf]="${!i}"
                ;;
        esac
    done

    # execute the appropriate command and reformat the output
    if [ $nf -eq 0 ]; then
        local binfmt='s/$/ *-/;' txtfmt='s/$/  -/;'
        if [ -n "$binary" ]; then
            fmt=$binfmt
        else
            fmt=$txtfmt
        fi
        openssl dgst -sha1 -hex | sed -e "$fmt"
    else
        local commonfmt='s/^[A-Z0-9]\+(\(.*\))= \([0-9a-fA-F]\+\)$/\2'
        local binfmt="$commonfmt "'*\1/;' txtfmt="$commonfmt  "'\1/;'
        if [ -n "$binary" ]; then
            fmt=$binfmt
        else
            fmt=$txtfmt
        fi
        openssl dgst -sha1 -hex "${files[@]}" | sed -e "$fmt"
    fi
}

if ! type -p sha1sum &>/dev/null; then
    function sha1sum() { openssl_sha1sum "$@"; }
fi
```